# Text in pdf-file has mysterious spaces

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to export text to a pdf document using the standard PDFdocument class in android. The code creates a pdf but in the text I write to the PDF, it put mysterious spaces half in words.

Tried using the canvas.drawText option and the drawItemn option.
Both give the same result. The problem code-line is almost at the bottom of the sample code below.

```
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(mPageWidth, mPageHeight, pageNr).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = doc.startPage(pageInfo);

Memory memory = mMemoryData.get(pageNr);
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

//Header
Yposition = drawItem( canvas,
                      paint,
                      18,
                      true,
                      Xposition,
                      Yposition,
                      memory.getTitle() );

//line
Yposition += 14; //Extra offset to get some space between the text and line
paint.setColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.default_Accent) );
canvas.drawLine( Xposition, Yposition, pageInfo.getPageWidth() - Xposition, Yposition, paint );

Yposition += 20;
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(10);
// **this is the line that gives the problem**
canvas.drawText(memory.getText(),Xposition, Yposition, paint);

doc.finishPage(page);
```

The result of this action is:

[image: screen capture of PDF]

At first sight this looks ok but if you zoom in a bit or better yet copy/past the text into notepad (or something) you get this:

> No w le ts try this

In stead of the problem line, I also tried this:

```
drawItem( canvas, paint, 10, false, Xposition, Yposition, memory.getText() );
```

This has some benefits especially with bigger text but other that that it gives the same problem.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Such effects are typically seen when the viewer does not have access to the correct font and uses a replacement instead.

Comment: i tried setting the font ("Arial" but also tried the Typeface.Default) but did not work

    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create( "Arial",Typeface.NORMAL));

Comment: Update: found that setting the font the way i do doesn't do anything. i mean the font is not changed so i can also not see if the font is the problem.  Searching the internet i so far did not find how to set the font. I will update if i have more info, but love to hear if any of you have ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip from Henry the problem is now solved.
For others having the same problem:
i was close with the setting of the font but "Arial" just doesn't work
This also goes for "Typeface.SANS_SERIF". I kept getting these strange spaces in my text.

Now it put it like below.

`paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create( Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.NORMAL));`

Not the best looking text markup but it does the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same problem and found a solution that worked for me:

```
paint.setHinting(Paint.HINTING_OFF);
```

With text hinting enabled, the individual glyphs (characters) are placed on the PDF grid which appears to be 1/72 inch. Disabling text hinting places the glyphs where they should be, at least in my case.